# from an activity to new xml file without making new class for the xml

Tags: android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want to know if threre is a way to use a button.OnclickListener() to go from one activity to xml file without making a class for that xml.For example:

btn.OnClickListener(new OnclickListener(){

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

```
       Intent i = new Intent(ex.this, ex.class);
       startActivity(i);
```

}};

we use the intent to go from activity class to another new activity class, and in the new class there is setContentView(R.layout.example); in onCreate method, so the xml layout will be displayed.

but I ask if there is a way to display the xml layout withot making a class activity.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't if want to go to a new activity I believe you need a class.  You can do this programatically without any XML. 
(however I am reasonably new to android so could be wrong)